# Use the values of \title, \author and \date on a custom title page

Tags: titles

I am trying to create a title page of my own.

Is there a way to make use of the `\title`, `\author` and `\date` commands inside the title page?

For instance:

```
...
\title{Something Cool}
\author{Cool Dude}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}

The title is \title
It was written by \author on \date

\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Basically I just want to know if there is a way to leverage the information stored in `\title`, `\author` and `\date` inside the title page.

Comment: Also, note that `\date{\today}` is redundant since if you don't provide a `\date` command, `\maketitle` will automatically use the current date.

Comment: I'm not sure it's worth using these commands. I think that if the titlepage is created manually, title, author and date don't need to be used at all.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

The `\title`, `\author` and `\date` macros save their argument into `\@title`, `\@author`, and `\@date`, respectively. You can use these macros after [`\makeatletter`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/2975). Afterward, use [`\makeatother`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/2975). Note that they are cleared by `\maketitle`.

```
\title{Example}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}

% ...

\makeatletter
\begin{titlepage}

The title is \@title
It was written by \@author\space on \@date

\end{titlepage}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 89):

The [`titling`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titling) package provides various user-friendly ways to modify title pages.

It provides the macros `\thetitle`, `\theauthor` and `\thedate` which can be reused anywhere in your document.

It allows you to have multiple instances of `\title`, `\author` and `\date` and `\maketitle` itself in a single document. (If you don't use `titling`, `\maketitle` clears the values of `\@title`, `\@author` and `\@date` [cf. Martin's answer] after it has used them.)

It also provides various hooks for modifying the formatting of all of the component parts.

Comment: I just noticed I should rather have added my edit of August 24 as a comment. Sorry, I hope you didn't mind.

Comment: @doncherry Not at all.  It added a nice piece of clarification to the answer.

Comment: Note that you have to load `titling` (`\usepackage{titling}`) [before `\title`, `\author` and `\date` are defined](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27467/titlings-thetitle-theauthor-and-thedate-dont-work).

Comment: To me, this seems obvious, or am I missing something?  Load all packages, then start supplying content...

Comment: Well, for me, it wasn't. I guess it's because in learning LaTeX, I used `\title{...}` etc. before I used any packages, so they came first in the source; then, I liked seeing the meta-data at the very top of the source. The question I linked to describes the first (and so far only) time this meant trouble for me. Your "1) setup 2) content" approach makes a lot of sense, though. (Obviously, the note wasn't meant for you personally, but as a general pointer.)

Answer (score 28):

I understand your question as follows: How can I access the values of the title, author, and date fields somewhere in the document. I suggest the following MWE as an answer, which dispenses with the need to use `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother` outside of the preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Something}
\author{Somebody}
\date{Sometime}

\makeatletter
\let\newtitle\@title
\let\newauthor\@author
\let\newdate\@date
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Later in the document \ldots we access the variables again:
\newtitle, \newauthor, and \newdate.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17):

There exists a package exactly for this purpose: [authoraftertitle](http://ctan.org/pkg/authoraftertitle)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authoraftertitle}
\title{Something}
\author{Somebody}
\date{Sometime}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Later in the document \ldots we access the variables again:
\MyTitle, \MyAuthor, and \MyDate.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 16):

Another possibilty is to define metadata. Something like

```
\def\myauthor{Author} % Author
\def\mycoauthor{} % co-author
\def\mytitle{Title} % title
\def\mydate{Date} % date
%....
\begin{titlepage}

The title is \mytitle
It was written by \myauthor on \mydate

\end{titlepage}
```