# titling's \thetitle, \theauthor and \thedate don't work

Tags: errors, titles, titling

I was trying to use `\thetitle`, `\theauthor` and `\thedate` of the `titling` package, but none of them worked. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titling}

\begin{document}
\thetitle \theauthor \thedate
\end{document}
```

(updated MWE see below)

returns three errors:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.6 \thetitle
              \theauthor \thedate

! Undefined control sequence.
l.6 \thetitle \theauthor
                         \thedate

! Undefined control sequence.
l.6 \thetitle \theauthor \thedate
```

I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 (pdfTeX 1.40.12) with the most up-to-date version of `titling`, here's the `\listfiles` output:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 titling.sty    2009/09/04 v2.1d maketitle typesetting
```

---

### Edit:

Obviously, and stupidly, I forgot to define `\title`, `\author` and `\date` in above MWE. This wasn't the problem in my original document, though. The complete MWE (that still produces the same errors) would've looked like like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\author{John Doe}
\title{Foo Bar}
\date{\today}

\usepackage{titling}

\begin{document}
\thetitle \theauthor \thedate
\end{document}
```

Comment: See my edited answer

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titling}
\author{A. N. Author}
\title{A title}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thetitle \theauthor \thedate
\end{document}
```

You have to specify the data, otherwise they're not available.

Of course the **titling** package has to be loaded *before* defining title, author and date.

Comment: Ooops `:D` I totally forgot the data in my MWE. In the original document I'm working on, it was defined, however. I found the pitfall, however, I'll add it as an answer. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: If you want to be minimal, `\maketitle` isn't even necessary. (I was considering this as the source of the error at some point, i.e. `\maketitle` must be executed in order for `\thetitle` to work, which is _not_ the case.)

Answer (score 10):

The `titling` package needs to be called *before* `\title`, `\author` and `\date` are defined. To get the meta-data first in any source, I usually don't put any packages before it, but here it seems necessary. The following example works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titling}

\author{John Doe}
\title{Foo Bar}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\thetitle \theauthor \thedate
\end{document}
```

Interestingly, `\thedate` doesn't automatically function as `\today`, even though `\maketitle` will assume the date is today if you don't specify otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

You need to define the values of author, title and date before these can be called, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titling}
\title{this}
\author{him}
\date{13 July 2025}
\begin{document}
\thetitle \theauthor \thedate
\end{document}
```