# Are there any situtations where it is better to load a package after other code?

Tags: best-practices, incompatibility, preamble

I always place all my packages immediately following the document class, followed by setting information (`\hypersetup` for example) and customization to my documents (header and footer customization for example), and macros for use in the document.

Is there any case were you would want to load code before you load a package?

[This answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40785/7880) points out that for clarity you might want to have setting information immediately following the package, to reduce the amount of documentation you have to do (For example, I should move `\hypersetup` to be right after `\usepackage{hyperref}`, but before any packages that follow it, `achemso` or `cleverref` or whatever)

I thought all packages had to be loaded first, but it seems that in some cases you need code before them, [for example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49775/7880) [you need to set](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27467/titlings-thetitle-theauthor-and-thedate-dont-work) `\author`, `\title`, and `\date` before you load the `titling` package.

So, are there cases where it is technically better (or required) to write some code before loading a package? By technically better I mean, makes a difference to the compiler, not just someone reading the code later.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One situation in which you need some code before loading a package is to prevent name clashes. A little example: suppose you are using one of the AMS document classes and you want to use some command from the [`dingbat`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/dingbat) package, say `\leftpointright`; you then try

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{dingbat}

\begin{document}

\leftpointright

\end{document}
```

and receive the following error

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \checkmark already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

The problem is that the package `amsfonts` internally loaded by the AMS classes, defines `\checkmark` and the `dingbat` package also defined this command, producing a name clash. One possible solution is to use the [`savesym`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/savesym) package,  rename the conflicting symbol, and then load the dingbat package: `\savesymbol{XXX}` renames a symbol from `\XXX` to `\origXXX` thus preventing the name clash:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{savesym}
\savesymbol{checkmark}
\usepackage{dingbat}

\begin{document}

\leftpointright

\end{document}
```

[image]

This techniques was used extensively by Scott Pakin to build the *The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List*.

As a curiosity, the file associated to the `savesym` package is `savesym.sty` but the package says

```
\ProvidesPackage{savesymbol}[2003/06/01v1.1 Saves and restores symbols]
```

so you will get a (harmless) warning when using the package:

```
LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `savesym',
               but the package provides `savesymbol'.
```

Answer (score 5):

The [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) package uses `\parindent` to initialize the `\bibhang` length which controls the hanging indentation of bibliography entries. If you want `\parindent` and `\bibhang` to match, any changes to `\parindent` should be carried out before loading `biblatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{2.25em}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\newcommand*{\sometext}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
    adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac,
    adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu
    libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  addendum ={\sometext}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\sometext

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like a bug in the package: The code for initializing `\bibhang` should be executed with `\AtBeginDocument` to remove that dependency on code order.