# How can I use @author, @date, and @title after maketitle?

Tags: titles

I want to include the values of author, date, and title in my use of fancyhdr in a document that uses `\maketitle`. Googling about, I saw that `@date`, etc. can access the date, etc., values set in the document preamble. It works fine, *provided* `\maketitle` is not used. Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{Things about Stuff}
\author{Someone}
\date{Somewhen}

\begin{document}

%\maketitle  %Toggle comment and:

Now you see them, now you don't.

\makeatletter
\@date
\@author
\@title
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

So, 1) why does the use of `\maketitle` cause subsequent invocation of `@date`, etc. to yield nothing, and 2) how can I access the value of `\date`, etc after the use of `\maketitle`?

Comment: To answer 1) the normal `\maketitle` macro resets all of these macros: `\global \let \@author \@empty \global \let \@date \@empty \global \let \@title \@empty`

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Use the values of \title, \author and \date on a custom title page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10130/use-the-values-of-title-author-and-date-on-a-custom-title-page)

Comment: @Alan I don't think so. I did link to that other question in the answer that I gave below, but I could well imagine that someone might run into the difficulty that I did without having the interest in producing a custom title page. I added my question despite the existence of that one as mine seems to represent a distinct (way of arriving at the) problem. But, if the community disagrees, so be it :-)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\title{Things about Stuff}\let\Title\@title
\author{Someone}          \let\Author\@author
\date{Somewhen}           \let\Date\@date
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle 

Now you see them
\Date
\Author
\Title

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 34):

Use the `titling` package, which provides `\thedate`, `\theauthor`, `\thetitle` even after you've called `\maketitle`.

It's as simple as adding the package, and instead of calling `\@date` you call `\thedate` (which also avoids requiring `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titling}

\title{Things about Stuff}
\author{Someone}
\date{Somewhen}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Now you still see them.

\thedate
\theauthor
\thetitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Problem is "titling" package does not seem to work with beamer class..

Answer (score 13):

Checking this site before I posted this question, I saw that [this earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10130/use-the-values-of-title-author-and-date-on-a-custom-title-page) yielded the answer "use the titling package". That seems to work. But, I'd also come up with putting

```
\newcommand{\setdocdata}{
\title{Things about Stuff}
\author{Someone} 
\date{Somewhen}
}
\setdocdata{}
```

in my preamble and then using

```
\maketitle\setdocdata
```

which works, too, and might appeal to those who prefer to use as few packages as necessary.

(I still would like to know why, for the love of puppies, `\maketitle` was coded to blank the date, etc values.)