# Entering the title in the footer

Tags: header-footer, titles, fancyhdr

How do I insert the title in the footer? And decide if it is set or not?

```
%preteste.sty
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\title}[1]{\gdef\@title{#1}\gdef\mytitle{#1}}
\newcommand{\mytitle}{%
   \PackageErrorNoLine{pkgname}
     {No \protect\title\space given}
     {You have to provide a title}%
   \gdef\mytitle{You have to provide a title}%
   \mytitle
}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\mytitle}
```

See the error if no define `\title` and no use `\maketitle`

```
%titulo.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{preteste}

% \title{Title}
% \author{R\'egis S. Santos}
% \date{\the\year}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
% \maketitle

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

fix my code, please.

Comment: related/possible duplicates: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27710/how-can-i-use-author-date-and-title-after-maketitle, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10130/use-the-values-of-title-author-and-date-on-a-custom-title-page

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After `\maketitle` the title is forgotten. By the way, `\title` wouldn't print the title anyway: it's a command for declaring what the title is.

```
\newcommand{\mytitle}{Title}
\title{\mytitle}
...
\fancyfoot[C]{\mytitle}
```

If you need it in a package, then redefine `\title`:

```
\renewcommand{\title}[1]{\gdef\@title{#1}\gdef\mytitle{#1}}
...
\fancyfoot[C]{\mytitle}
```

This duplication will allow you to say normally

```
\title{Title}
\author{A. U. Thor}
\maketitle
```

in the document.

If you want to raise an error if the author doesn't provide a `\title` declaration, add to your package

```
\newcommand{\mytitle}{%
   \PackageError{preteste}% use the package name
     {No \protect\title\space given\@gobble}
     {You have to provide a title}%
   \gdef\mytitle{You have to provide a title}%
   \mytitle}
```

After raising the error, it will redefine itself to print an informative message in the footer. The `\title` declaration in the document will clear this definition, so there's nothing to worry about.

The titling package can be used, but maybe it's too much for this simple application.

Comment: I've used this method, but I put the ``\fancyfoot[C]{\title}`` a file.sty, then it will not work. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Read egreg's answer more carefully: you need to put `fancyfoot[C]{\mytitle}` not `\title`.

Comment: Also make sure that you load your `file.sty` after you have loaded the `fancyhdr` package, and after you have defined `\mytitle`

Comment: Thanks egreg, but how to verify ``\ifdefined\@title`` or similar, if the title is not set.

Comment: @RegisdaSilva See edited message

Comment: @egreg I edited my question. See you again, please.

Comment: @RegisdaSilva An error by me: one should always check and not rely on memory. :(

Comment: but my code is correct?

Comment: @RegisdaSilva I've corrected the code

Answer (score 2):

I think an easy solution involves the following instructions in the document's preamble *after* the `\title`, `\author`, and `\date` commands have been set up:

```
\makeatletter
\let\doctitle\@title
\makeatother
```

You can then insert the title string in the footer as follows:

```
\fancyfoot[C]{\doctitle}
```

Finally, if you want to put all of this stuff in a package, be sure to invoke this package only *after* the `\title` has been set up and the `fancyhdr` package has been loaded. Happy TeXing!