# How can I access the currently specified date in \rfoot?

Tags: header-footer, titles

I'm using `\date` to specify my document's date for `\maketitle`. I would like to use the same date in my footer. Currently I have to enter the date twice: once in `\date` and once in `\rfoot`. Is there a way I can enter the date a single time and have `\maketitle` and `\rfoot` both use the same date?

Here's an excerpt from my original document:

```
\date{December 12, 2012}

\rfoot{December 12, 2012}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
```

I found a related question: [How can I use @author, @date, and @title after maketitle?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27710) so I tried this:

```
\date{December 12, 2012} \let\Date\@date

\rfoot{\Date}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
```

But that gives me an error:

```
./MyDoc.tex:45: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}
.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.45 \date{December 12, 2012} \let\Date\@d
                                          ate
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `makeatletter` and `makeatother` as in this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}

\makeatletter
\title{This is title}\let\Title\@title
\author{Your name}          \let\Author\@author
\date{December 12, 2012}           \let\Date\@date
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rfoot{\Date}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just adding `\makeatletter` was enough to make it work. Now I'll do some research to figure out what it's doing.

Comment: @SSteve It's safer to also add `\makeatother`; in a `.tex` file, `\makeatletter` changes the catcode of `@` from 12 to 11 (to make it a "regular" letter) and  `\makeatother` reverts this and assigns to `@` catcode 12 again.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I will do that. Thanks for the tip.