# use of \author after maketitle

Tags: titles

I would like to know if it is possible insert  the author anywhere in the document.
Suppose I´ve already defined `\author{}` and then in some part of my document I want to write it, is any command that does that?

Comment: And what about when is a command i have done like \newcommand{\faculty}[1]{\def\@faculty{#1}}

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please have a look at question http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27710/5001 and decide if the answers given there address your question as well.