# How does one fetch the arguments of \title and \author?

Tags: titles

When using the simple `\maketitle` command, one can use `\title`, `\author`, `\date` etc to define the corresponding contents. Now if one desires to for example make a custom title page, how can this information then be retrieved?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\title{My report}
\author{Me \and Myself}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
%\thetitle?
%\theauthor?
%\thedate?
\end{titlepage}
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

Comment: something like this? [How can I use @author, date, and title after maketitle?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27710)

Comment: Your question is actually really open. First of all, I suggest you to follow this [nice documentation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation), which describes well on how to create a customised title page. In case you encounter further specific issues, please do not hesitate to ask us.

Comment: @cmhughes Precisely, thanks, although the absence of `\maketitle` makes http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10130/ perhaps more applicable. Let's consider this a duplicate.

Comment: ok, that's great, glad you got what you needed :)