# \@ title and You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode

Tags: errors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do)

I'm trying to use a template with the following content:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10.5pt]{report}
\usepackage{a4wide}

\usepackage{styles/thesis_style}
\usepackage{styles/functions}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont[BoldFont={Helvetica Bold},ItalicFont={Helvetica Oblique}]{Helvetica}

\title{Towards Storing Point Clouds in PostgreSQL}
\author{Michel Ott}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\include{./titlepage}
```

Then in the ./titlepage file there is the following:

```
{ \huge \bfseries \@title}\\[2cm]
...
```

Now I get the following error:

```
! You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode. \@->\spacefactor \@m {} l.29 
{ \huge \bfseries \@ title}\\[2cm] ?
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: @melbic  The `@` is the problem see the link quoted by egreg.

Comment: The linked question treats the problem, but to an un-experienced user it might not give the clue as what to do. Hence I vote to reopen.

Comment: It is infuriating that I am looking for the exact same answer @melbic is looking for, but instead of a simple and concrete solution, it is closed with a link to a semi-related broad-topic question. Just... why?

Comment: After a bit more research, I think using the `titling` package from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10133/163196) is way more straight-forward than trying to get `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` to work.

Comment: I had such an error by using `\@ifundefined` with the compulsory `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` inside a `\newcommand` definition. I had to put `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` **outside** the `\newcommand` definition, surrounding it. ´:-)