# You can't use \spacefactor in vertical mode

Tags: front-matter

The following code returns the error message in the title

```
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \begin{document}
      \begin{titlepage}%
            \noindent
            \includegraphics[viewport=8 8 185 55]{picture} \hfill
             \vspace{-6pt}

        \vspace{3cm}

        \let\footnotesize\small
        \let\footnoterule\relax
        \let \footnote \thanks

        \begin{center}
            \begin{spacing}{1.8}
              {\huge \bfseries \@title}
            \end{spacing}
            
            \large \@thesistype
        \end{center}

        \vspace{0.4cm}
        
        \begin{center}
            \large
            \@author

            \texttt{\small \@email}
        \end{center}%

        \vspace{0.4cm}

        \begin{center}
            \@institute
        \end{center}

        \vspace{1cm}

        \ifx \@logo \@empty
            \relax
        \else
        \begin{center}
            \@logo
        \end{center}
        \fi

        \vfill
        \begin{center}
            \textbf{Supervisors:} \\[2pt] \@supervisors
        \end{center}

        \vspace{0.2cm}
        
        \begin{center}
            \@date
        \end{center}
  \end{titlepage}%
\end{document}
```

A very similar problem is discussed here:
[\@ title and You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54097/title-and-you-cant-use-spacefactor-in-vertical-mode)
However, I am too inexperienced to figure out what to do exactly. For example, I don't understand what command I am redefining that is so problematic. The incriminated line is
`{\huge \bfseries \@title}`. Any easy fixes for this?

Comment: you need to surround code using `@` with `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother` (or put it in a `.sty` package file)

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle. It worked on the incriminated line. However when I do this around  \large \@thesistype. I define it in the preamble as \newcommand\thesistype[1]{\gdef \@thesistype{#1}} but it still does not work: "undefined control sequence"

Comment: `\makeatletter\newcommand\thesistype[1]{\gdef\@thesistype{#1}}\makeatother`, you have to put the `\makeatletter` around the definition, not inside it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Skillmon. It works everywhere now, and I get no error message, however the logo is not actually loaded and does not appear in the front page although it is in the overleaf folder. I load it with \logo{filename.png}

Comment: Instead of the logo itself, the filename gets printed on the page.

Comment: @Alex most likely because `\logo` only stores the file name inside `\@logo`, but we can't really reproduce because that's missing in your question. My bet is use `\includegraphics{\@logo}` in your `titlepage` instead of just `\@logo` (but don't change the `\@logo` in the `\ifx` line).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151019/discussion-between-alex-and-skillmon).