# Access title and author in custom class

Tags: titles, documentclass-writing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use the values of \title, \author and \date on a custom title page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10130/use-the-values-of-title-author-and-date-on-a-custom-title-page)

How can I access the title and author in my custom class based on article, so that I can insert them in the footer that I automatically set up?

I tried `\@title` and `\@author` but nothing shows up.

Comment: Note that the base document classes define `\title` and `\author` that redefines the values of `\@title` and `\@author`, used when issuing `\maketitle`. Perhaps you can elaborate more on what you mean by "access the title and author".

Comment: I mean I want to write in my `.cls` file, `\fancyfoot[C]{AUTHOR—TITLE}`, for example. I tried using `\@title` and `@author` there but when I run pdflatex, the footer is simply `—`.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [Use the values of \title \author and \date in a custom title page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10130/2693)

Comment: @Mk12: In order for this to *not* be considered a duplicate by others, you need to include your comment about modifying the footer to your liking.

Comment: I said I want to insert them in the footer from a custom class in the original post, didn't I?

Comment: [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/631472/65440) did it for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\@title` and `\@author` are technically only defined once you use `\title` and `\author`:

```
\def\title#1{\gdef\@title{#1}}
\def\@title{\@latex@error{No \noexpand\title given}\@ehc}
\def\author#1{\gdef\@author{#1}}
\def\@author{\@latex@warning@no@line{No \noexpand\author given}}
```

That is, if you reference `\@title` and/or `\@author` *without* calling `\title` and `\author` first, it should produce a warning. To avoid this situation, based on the fact that you're writing a special class, you could use a different approach:

```
\let\@title\@empty
\let\@author\@empty
\fancyfoot[C]{\ifx\@author\@empty\else\@author~--~\fi\ifx\@title\@empty\else\@title\fi}
```

The above sets the footer to be `AUTHOR - TITLE` if both are defined. It will only be `TITLE` if no author is defined. It can be expanded to properly work if an author is given but no title.

Here's a minimal example using [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) and [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\makeatletter
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\ifx\@author\@empty\else\@author~--~\fi\ifx\@title\@empty\else\@title\fi}
\let\@title\@empty
\let\@author\@empty
\makeatother

\title{My title}
\author{Me}
\pagestyle{fancy}%
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}​
```

---

If you're actually using `\maketitle` as well, you need a little more work done. The MWE below adds `\@@title` and `\@@author` instead of `\@title` and `\@author`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\makeatletter
\def\title#1{\gdef\@title{#1}\gdef\@@title{#1}}
\def\author#1{\gdef\@author{#1}\gdef\@@author{#1}}
\let\@@title\@empty
\let\@@author\@empty
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\ifx\@@author\@empty\else\@@author~--~\fi\ifx\@@title\@empty\else\@@title\fi}

\title{My title}
\author{Me}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}%
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: hmm, I tried that but they still aren't showing up…

Comment: Oh, it's because I have `\maketitle`… Should I use the titling package then if I want to kept maketitle?

Comment: @Mk12: I've updated my solution to include your `\maketitle` usage requirement.