# Define options similar to \title, \author and \date

Tags: document-classes, article, variable

I'm creating my own class based on `article` and I would like to add a parameter `subtitle` which users of my class can set similar to `title`, `author` and `date`, e.g.,

```
\documentclass{myclass}
\title{My title} % This sets `\@title` to `My title` somehow.
\subtitle{Some subtitle} % I want this to set `\@subtitle` to `Some subtitle`.

\begin{document}
\makebanner % this command uses \@title and \@subtitle under the hood
\end{document}
```

Looking at the source code of [`article.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls?view=co), the `title` command seems to be defined as follows.

```
\global\let\@title\@empty
\global\let\title\relax
```

This doesn't really make sense to me, so I think I'm missing something. Also, adding `\global\let\@subtitle\@empty` and `\global\let\subtitle\relax` doesn't work. What is a proper way to do this? How does `article.cls` do it?

Comment: `\global\let\@subtitle\@empty` and `\protected\long\def\subtitle#1{\gdef\@subtitle{#1}}` does the trick. The `\global\let\title\relax` is executed inside of `\maketitle`. The real definition of `\title` is done by the kernel and not part of `article.cls`.

Comment: Of course. The reason is in the comment above: the LaTeX kernel defines `\title`, `article.cls` just uses an existing definition.

Comment: @Skillmon Okay, that explains a lot. You may add an answer if you want.

Answer (score 3):

In `ltsect.dtx` the LaTeX kernel makes the following definitions:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\title[1]{\gdef\@title{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\author[1]{\gdef\@author{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\date[1]{\gdef\@date{#1}}
\def\@title{\@latex@error{No \noexpand\title given}\@ehc}
\def\@author{\@latex@warning@no@line{No \noexpand\author given}}
\def\@date{\today}
```

The standard classes (like `article.cls`) don't define those commands, they use the existing definitions. The "definitions" you saw are not their definitions, just the redefinitions done to make them unavailable once `\maketitle` was used.

For this reason, the definitions you could use would be:

```
\let\@subtitle\@empty % default value
\protected\def\subtitle#1{\gdef\@subtitle{#1}}
```

(`\protected\def` results in similar behaviour to `\DeclareRobustCommand`, pick whichever you prefer)