# adding co-authors to customised title page for beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, titles

I have customised my title page, using `\title` `\date` and `\institute`. I would like to add another line with co-authors, but I couldn't find any examples of how to do it. My ideas at the moment are

1. I could hi-jack `\insertshortinstitute`, since I don't use this in anywhere else.
2. I could define a new variable e.g. `\def\mycoauthor{}` (like on [Use the values of \title, \author and \date on a custom title page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10130/use-the-values-of-title-author-and-date-on-a-custom-title-page)) but then I don't know how to access it, especially since my maketitle definite is in a separate style file.

Here is a MWE showing how I create the title page at the moment, and an attempt to include coauthors:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usetheme{_MWE}

\title[short title]{TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE}
\author[me]{A. U. Thor}
\def\coauthors{A. N. Other, J. Bloggs, J. Doe}
\institute[\coauthors]{My Institute}
\date{1.1.2012}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

`beamertheme_MWE.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{beamertheme_MWE}

\makeatletter
\def\maketitle{%
\begin{frame}[plain]
{%
 \vspace{10mm}
 \parbox{122mm}%
  {%
   \centering
   {\Large \inserttitle}\\
   \vspace{8mm}
   {\large \insertauthor}\\
   \vspace{3mm}
   {\large \insertshortinstitute}
   \vspace{7mm}
   {\small \insertinstitute}\\
   \vspace{-5mm}
   {\flushleft
    \hspace{1mm}
    LOGO1
    \hspace{60mm}
    \raisebox{0.5mm}{
        LOGO2
    \hspace{10mm}
    }
  }\\
  \vspace{0mm}
  {
   \parbox{53mm}{\centering \small \insertdate\\
   }
  }
 }
}
\end{frame}
  }
\makeatother
```

incidentally... why doesn't the `\centering` command work for `\insertshortinstitute`, and why do I get an error "there's no line here to end" if I put a `\\` after it, as I do with `\author` etc.?

Comment: I should add that I don't want to use the `\thanks` construct, since I don't think superscripts are the right way to refer to co-authors... unless someone knows a way to use `\thanks` and get the formatting I want?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think `\author` uses a minipage internally, so you can use something like

```
\author[me]{A. U. Thor\\[3mm]A. N. Other, J. Bloggs, J. Doe}
```

and forget `\coauthors` except you want to use them somewhere else.

If you use this construction, delete `\insertshortinstitue` form your style.

Comment: thanks, that gives me what I want. I forgot to mention before, but I also wanted to change the font size. That works the same way, so what I've got now is:  
`code`
\def\coauthors{A. N. Other, J. Bloggs, J. Doe}  
\author[me]{A. U. Thor\\[3mm]\small \coauthors}  
\institute[my institute]{My Institute}
`code`
(and of course I removed the line with `\insertshortinstitute` in the style file)

Comment: I have a follow-up question: when I moved this solution from my MWE back to my real presentation, the new author line conflicts with another package in my style file: `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`. Other options to inputenc (ansinew, latin1 and latin9) compile with no problems. The error message I get is: ! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
}
l.6 ...3mm] \small A. N. Other, J. Bloggs, J. Doe}
[etc....etc....etc...]
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

Do you know what's going on here, or how to get around it?

Comment: added as separate question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81641/adding-vertical-space-conflicts-with-inputenc-using-utf8x-only