# adding vertical space conflicts with inputenc using utf8x only

Tags: titles, minipage, input-encodings

For context, this question was raised by the answer to a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79842/adding-co-authors-to-customised-title-page-for-beamer-presentation/79864#comment171846_79864).

I'm trying to design a title page for a beamer presentation, although this could be a more general issue. I use the minipage capabilities of the \author command to add a second line with co-authors. When adding vertical space between the lines, using `[3mm]` gives an error, but `\vspace{3mm}` works. The error only appears when the inputenc package is loaded with the option utf8x. Using `utf8`, `ansinew`, `latin1` or `latin9` worked fine.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usetheme{_MWE}

\title[short title]{TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE}
%\author[me]{A. U. Thor \\ [3mm] A. N. Other, J. Bloggs, J. Doe}
\author[me]{A. U. Thor \\ \vspace{3mm} A. N. Other, J. Bloggs, J. Doe}
\institute[my institute]{My Institute}
\date{1.1.2012}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

and the style file:

```
\ProvidesPackage{beamertheme_MWE}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    % most systems, modern linux
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}    % most systems, modern linux
%\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}    % Windows
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}    % unix and vms
%\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}    % newer latin, includes euro sign and fractions

\makeatletter
\def\maketitle{%
\begin{frame}[plain]
{%
 \vspace{10mm}
 \parbox{122mm}%
  {%
   \centering
   {\Large \inserttitle}\\
   \vspace{8mm}
   {\large \insertauthor}\\
   \vspace{10mm}
   {\small \insertinstitute}\\
   \vspace{-5mm}
   {\flushleft
    \hspace{1mm}
    LOGO1
    \hspace{60mm}
    \raisebox{0.5mm}{
        LOGO2
    \hspace{10mm}
    }
  }\\
  \vspace{0mm}
  {
   \parbox{53mm}{\centering \small \insertdate\\
   }
  }
 }
}
\end{frame}
  }
\makeatother
```

Comment: wouldn't you know it... it's probably something to do with this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13067/utf8x-vs-utf8-inputenc utf8x is apparently obsolete and incompatible with several packages.

Comment: I think it's not good policy to load `inputenc` in a package (or Beamer theme): this limits users to what the package wants. The problem, however, is not due to this, but to the fact that `utf8x` is not fully compatible with `beamer`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good idea putting a call to `inputenc` in a package: this forces you (or the users of the theme) to have a predetermined encoding of your file. But the theme is independent of UTF-8, as far as I can see, so it's preferable to have the call in the document's preamble.

The problem seems to be involved with the `\PrerenderUnicode` command of `ucs.sty` and this means that `utf8x` and `beamer` are incompatible, at least in some aspects; the same problem appears when only `utf8x` is loaded and not your personalized theme.

On the other hand there's no real reason why using `utf8x`; for Greek support there is the new LGRx suite that makes Greek input possible with the `utf8` option to `inputenc`. For single Unicode characters that aren't covered, you can use `newunicodechar` to provide a definition.