# Add collaborators' name in beamer title slide

Tags: beamer, titles

How to add collaborators' name (perhaps their respective institute also) in the title slide for beamer?

I don't want them to appear at the bottom of every slide.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Use the optional for `authors`. `\author[short author names]{author names}`.

Comment: I asked a similar question once, and got an answer which worked well for me: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79842/adding-co-authors-to-customised-title-page-for-beamer-presentation

Comment: @Sigur Wanna write that as a short answer to get the question  off the list of unanswered?

Comment: @Johannes_B, done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the optional argument to `\author`.

```
\author[short author names]{author names}
```