# Format title output bold and larger

Tags: formatting, titles

I use the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsxtra,amssymb,latexsym, amscd,amsthm}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}

\begin{document}
\title{Tại sao lý thuyết Maxwell lại khó hiểu?}     
\author{Dịch bởi: Nguyễn Duy Khánh}   
\date{18-12-2012}  

\maketitle

\section*{Khiêm tốn không phải lúc nào cũng là đức hạnh}
\end{document}
```

And here is the result, you can see the title is not bold and it is small, but the section is in bold and large

[image: And here is the result:]

Could you please show me which code I can use to have result like this : 
[image]

Comment: Hey, I changed the formatting of your code to be code instead of block quote :)

Comment: 1. Specify it directly `\title{\Large\bfseries Tại …}`, 2. use another class, e.g. `scrartcl` uses a better title formatting in my opinion, 3. custom designed `titlepage` environment (→ [Use the values of \title, \author and \date on a custom title page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10130))

Comment: What about the section title ? How can I make the two lines as in the second picture ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can design your own title section using `\@title`, `\@author` and `\@date`; a little example (feel free to change the settings according to your particular needs):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsxtra,amssymb,latexsym, amscd,amsthm}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}

\title{Tại sao lý thuyết Maxwell lại khó hiểu?}     
\author{Dịch bởi: Nguyễn Duy Khánh}   
\date{18-12-2012}  

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\hfil\parbox[t]{0.7\textwidth}{\centering\LARGE\bfseries\@title}\par
\kern0.7cm \hrule\kern0.5cm
\hfil\parbox[t]{0.7\textwidth}{\centering\bfseries\@author\\[3ex]\@date}\par
\kern0.5cm \hrule\kern0.5cm
\makeatother

\section{Test Section}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately I am unable to upload images right now; I'll do so as soon as I can.

Comment: can you upload the image yet?