# Access values within \newcommand

Tags: macros

I am a LaTeX user with moderate experience. However, I am trying to create my own `.cls` file for the first time. I would like to produce a header in a similar fashion to how title is produced in article class. Something along the following lines.

```
\documentclass{MyResume}

\name{Your Name}
\phone{281038901}
\email{xyz@example.com}

\begin{document}
 \maketitlebox
\end{document}
```

I know the basics of how to use `\newcommand`s to define these. But, I am not able to figure out how to access values of the fields like `\name`, `\phone` inside the definition of `\headerbox`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! One usually says `\newcommand\name[1]{\gdef\rajvi@name{#1}}` and then uses `\rajvi@name` when the actual name is needed; `rajvi` stands for the prefix you'll be using for the macros in your class.

Comment: See also here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10130/use-the-values-of-title-author-and-date-on-a-custom-title-page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick generally used is to say in the class file

```
\newcommand{\name}[1]{\gdef\rajvi@name{#1}}
```

and then using `\rajvi@name` where needed.

You should supplement this with a default definition, such as

```
\def\rajvi@name{%
  \ClassWarningNoLine{rajvi}{No \protect\name\space supplied}%
  ??%
}
```

so that the user will be warned about missing data and a pair of question marks will appear in the output. This might be made into an error, just choose the way you prefer.

With `rajvi` I mean the common prefix (often the class name) you use for avoiding macro conflicts.