# How to put \title in the header?

Tags: header-footer, titles, fancyhdr

I am just starting with TeX so please be tolerant for my lack of knowledge.

I am using `fancyhdr` for footers and headers and I would like to put the title from `\title` into `\fancyhead{}`

How can I do it ?

My code :

```
%usepackages and all sorts of stuff
%...

% ------
% Header/footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyhead[C]{\title}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}


% ------
% Clickable URLs (optional)
\usepackage{hyperref}

% ------
% Maketitle metadata
\title{\vspace{-15mm}%
    \fontsize{24pt}{10pt}\selectfont
    \textbf{Android}
    }   
\author{%
    \large
    \textsc{Patryk} \\[2mm]
    \normalsize University\\
    \vspace{-9mm}
    }
\date{\today}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}

% ...
% ...
```

Comment: I agree that one might expect this to work. Nevertheless, I do not think you want the title (as you defined it) to appear in the headerlines like that. Solution: `\def\mytitle{Android}`, and substitute `\mytitle` for `Android`; and put `\mytitle` in your fancyhdr definition.

Comment: Related (and effectively a duplicate) question: [Use the values of \title, \author and \date on a custom title page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10130)