# Breaking title page into multiple pages

Tags: page-breaking, titles, front-matter

I am writing an article and they ask of the following format

First page: paper title, authors’ name(s) and affiliation(s).
Second page: paper title and abstract
Third page: paper title and the main text.

I have the following structure

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
        \title{My Title}
        \author{That's me}
        \address{Affiliation goes here}
\end{frontmatter}       

\newpage
        \title{My Title}

        \begin{abstract}
            Lorem ipsum something something
        \end{abstract}
        
        \begin{keyword}
            Keywords here
        \end{keyword}

\newpage
\title {My Title}

\section{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum something something


\end{document}
```

It doesn't show first two pages. I tried to use `\begin{frontmatter}` `\end{frontmatter}` and it replicates author info at every page. How do I adjust what they want?

Comment: Well, you are already using the `elsarticle` template. So I would assume if you are indeed planning to submit to Elsevier, and the template you use is the recent template they provide and you used it according to instructions, then what you get is what they want. What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: Elsevier actually offers quite an [in-depth manual](https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/pdf_file/0008/56843/elsdoc-1.pdf) for their template. If you stick to it, I am sure you will create a manuscript that fits their needs.

Comment: I'm actually sending it to a competition and not sending it to Elsevier but my advisor insists on using this format. So, I've got to stick to it while maintaining the competition's standards.

Comment: If you can use the `titling` package, it should allow you to reuse/remake title pages multiple times in the document. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10130/use-the-values-of-title-author-and-date-on-a-custom-title-page) for example.