# How to insert an image at the top center of the first page?

Tags: graphics, header-footer, article, footer, covers

I would like to insert a logo in the top center of the first page, before the title and the authors name. If I use the command \begin{figure} it turns out another new page before the title with the image. I have also tried not to use \begin{figure}.
The main text code is below:

```
 %\documentclass[5p,sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn,authoryear]{elsarticle}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@pprintTitle{%
 \let\@oddhead\@empty
 \let\@evenhead\@empty
 \def\@oddfoot{\footnotesize\itshape
      \hfill\today}%
 \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\makeatother

\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}
\renewenvironment{abstract}{\global\setbox\absbox=\vbox\bgroup
\hsize=\textwidth\def\baselinestretch{1}%
\noindent\unskip\textbf{Abstract}
\par\medskip\noindent\unskip\ignorespaces}
{\egroup}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
exponent-product = \cdot,
output-decimal-marker  =  {,}, 
separate-uncertainty = true,
per-mode = symbol,
group-digits = false,
}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{.85}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{.7}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{.15}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{.66}
\setcounter{topnumber}{3}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{2}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{10}
\usepackage{flafter}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}


\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{chemformula} %chemical formulas can be written more easily using \ch
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{amsmath} % lar deg dele opp equations
\usepackage{mathtools} % dele opp eq.
\usepackage{titlesec}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}


%For at section, subsection og subsubsection skal bli deecent
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{10}{13}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{10}{13}\selectfont}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}

\urlstyle{same}




\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\centering\includegraphics[width = .8\linewidth]{img/logo-polimi_600x250.png}

\title{Laboratory experiment 1: Magnetic Nanoparticles}

\author{}
\address{}

\begin{abstract}
text 
\end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}

\input{text/01_Introduction}
\input{text/02_Materials&methods}
\input{text/03_Results&discussion}
\input{text/04_Conclusion}

\makeatother
\bibliographystyle{babunsrt}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please, check [https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What makes a good MWE?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe). Remove unnecessary packages and keep only to ones that interferes with your issue. By the way, avoid inserting `\input`s, since other people don't have the file, specially when they are not related to the question.

Comment: Please provide a document that we can compile without errors. Did you run your code? There are errors in your preamble, you use files we don't have, and other problems. I have tried to make it compilable but gave up as it was taking too much effort.

Comment: You should really fix the package conflicts, and the re-loading of `appendix` three times before you do everything else. If you're making this many changes, are you sure `elsarticle` is the right document class?

Answer (score 1):

I relented and produced a very cut down version of your MWE and placed a graphic above your title.

```
% logoprob.tex  SE 637240

 %\documentclass[5p,sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn,authoryear]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}   %%%% PW added for the image

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
%\centering\includegraphics[width = .8\linewidth]{img/logo-polimi_600x250.png}

  \title{{\begin{center}\includegraphics{example-image-a}\end{center}}
    \vspace{1cm}Laboratory experiment 1: Magnetic Nanoparticles}

\author{A. N. Author}
\address{Somewhere}

\begin{abstract}
text 
\end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Here too I suggest using `\texorpdfstring` inside `\title{...}` to prevent the extra commands from getting in to the PDF metadata.

Answer (score 0):

I removed all packages and other commands except for the section `\makeatletter\def\ps@pprintTitle` (it removes the *Preprint submitted to Elsevier*).

The *lazy* solution I applied was to insert `\centering\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-1x1}\\` inside the definition of title. Not the most elegant solution, but a simple one. I replaced your figure for one from the standard installation `example-image`.

I also added the package `lipsum` to better visualize the contents from abstract and sections.

Suggestions for creating your own customized title page:

- [How to customize my titlepage?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage)
- [Use the values of \title, \author and \date on a custom title page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10130/use-the-values-of-title-author-and-date-on-a-custom-title-page)
- https://pt.overleaf.com/learn/latex/How_to_Write_a_Thesis_in_LaTeX_(Part_5)%3A_Customising_Your_Title_Page_and_Abstract

A MWE follows:

```
\documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn,authoryear]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{\centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-1x1}\\
  Laboratory experiment 1:\\
  Magnetic Nanoparticles}

\author{Author}
\address{Address}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@pprintTitle{%
  \let\@oddhead\@empty
  \let\@evenhead\@empty
  \def\@oddfoot{\footnotesize\itshape
    \hfill\today}%
  \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
  \begin{abstract}
    \lipsum[65-68]
  \end{abstract}
\end{frontmatter}

\section{First section}
  
\lipsum[66-67]
  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I suggest using `\texorpdfstring` inside `\title{...}` to prevent the extra commands from getting in to the PDF metadata.