# How to get the value of the document title?

Tags: titles, best-practices

In the attempt of reproducing the layout of a book, I need to use the title of the book in one of the headings. Specifically, using `fancyhdr`, I'd do something like this

```tex
\fancyhead[CE]{\scshape \lowercase{the title of the book}}
```

However, even though I could hardcode the title of the book in there, I'd rather avoid it, because most likely I'll use that title elsewhere (in the cover, which I'd do with LaTeX as well, but also in first page, or whatever).

So my inclination is to do something like this,

```tex
\title{the title of the book}
```

and then use `\thetitle` or something whenever I needed it. However, I'm not sure what is the proper way of doing it.

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522173/how-to-get-the-value-of-the-document-title-in-latex) question on StackOverflow, which has answers of various ages. [The most recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61623361/5825294) suggests to `\usepackage{authoraftertitle}`+`\MyTitle`, while another suggests to `\renewcommand{\title}` so that `\title` also defines `\thetitle`.

---

[The suggested existing question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10130/use-the-values-of-title-author-and-date-on-a-custom-title-page) gives an answer, but I can't seem to apply it directly to my usecase.

For instance, this doesn't work (I'm not reporting the errors, because I'm sure expert readers know why it's wrong, even if I don't),

```tex
\fancyhead[CE]{\scshape \lowercase{\makeatletter\@title\makeatother}}
```

whereas this only partially works, as `\lowercase` seems to be ineffective,

```tex
\makeatletter
\fancyhead[CE]{\scshape \lowercase{\@title}}
\makeatother
```

---

It turns out that this works

```tex
\makeatletter
\fancyhead[CE]{\scshape \MakeLowercase{\@title}}
\makeatother
```

but I don't know why. Maybe an explanation or at least a hint about why this works woud be nice.

Comment: @Marijn, I've updated the question. Yes, that answer gives me a lot, but I'm still curious about why the solution works.

Comment: The way `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` work is that they make the @ character a normal character if the commands are executed when the code is loaded and all the commands are 'tokenized' as it is called. This means the first variant does not work because `\@title` is encountered when the file is loaded, but `\makeatletter` is not executed at that point because it is inside of the `\fancyhead` declaration. As a rule of thumb `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` should always be at the 'main' level of the code and never inside a command or environment.

Comment: The difference between `\lowercase` and `\MakeLowercase` is exactly what you have encountered, i.e., one is a low-level command that tries to change case of the input directly, while the other is a more complex ('expandable') macro that can be used inside of other complex macros.